# Finding records by a slug instead of id in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, activerecord, model-view-controller, routes

I am trying to create semantic URLs for a simple miniblog app, but am stuck with `to_param` and retrieving the records. This is the `Post` model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_slug

  validates :title, :body, :presence => true
  validates :title, length: { maximum: 250 }
  validates :body, length:  { maximum: 5000 }

  def to_param
    slug
  end

  private
  def create_slug
    self.slug = slugify
  end

  def slugify
    [year_month_day, title.parameterize].join("-")
  end

  def year_month_day
    [created_at.year, created_at.strftime("%m"), created_at.strftime("%d")].join
  end
end
```

Now, every time I'm linking to posts with `link_to @post.title, @post` I get this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

The `show` action looks like this:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find_by_slug(params[:id])
end
```

When I do the above it tries to find the post with the slug as the id, but the slug is not the id so I get an error. When I use the standard `find(params[:id])` it cannot find the record because `to_param` is overridden.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `after_create :create_slug` to `before_create :create_slug`.

If you want to use after_create, you have to save the object after you set the slug.

Comment: That solved it, thanks! I didn't think you could call `before_create` passing in a method that relies on the `created_at` field.